# Create a UIBarButtonItem with a title, and an image, and the default background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create a UIBarButtonItem that looks like the normal Apple ones, but I'd like to include an image and a piece of text.

As far as I can tell, you can't specify both an image and a title (the image shows but the title doesn't if you set both).

Also, if you use a customView, then you lose the BarButtonItem look and feel.

What's the best thing to do here? Mimic the artwork and use a customView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mimic the artwork and use a custom view is what we did with our apps.. Seems to be the only way.